# Evaluating the sum of a partial geometric sequence using Sigma notation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have a worksheet from my instructor with this problem on it, but the solution he has given is different from what I got, and I don't know why.

I'm not sure how to input the Greek letter sigma, but what it tells me is that I need to start with 1 ($k=1$), and end with $k=50$. The formula I am told to use is $3(-2)^{k-1}$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{50} 3(-2)^{k-1} $$

With this I found that $a=3$ and the common ratio is $-2$, so I used the partial sum of geometric sequences $a \frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$ I came up with this:

$$3\cdot\frac{1-(-2)^{50}}{1-(-2)} = 3\cdot\frac{1-2^{50}}3 = 1-2^{50}$$

but according to my math professor the solution is this

$$3\cdot\frac{1-(-2)^{50}}{1-2} = 3\cdot2^{50}-3$$

What did I do wrong? I asked him about it via e-mail, but I haven't received a response and I have a test tomorrow morning.

Comment: Hint: the sum formula that you used is valid for powers from $0$ to $n-1$.

Comment: If the common ratio is in fact $r = -2$, then your calculation is correct.

Comment: "*I'm not sure how to input the Greek letter sigma*" - Check out [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a primer on how to format mathematics on the site.  In particular, you are looking for \sum\limits_{k=1}^{50} to output $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{50}$

Answer (score 1):

From what I can interpret from what you have written, your answer appears to be correct. The denominator should be $(1-(-2))$ and not $(1-2)$.